# why I get python exception "OperationFailure: local.oplog.rs missing. did you drop it? if so restart server" every morning on CI?

Tags: python, mongodb, replication

Lately, we set mongodb on our CI to ReplicaSet. We have two nodes localhost:27017, localhost:27018 and the arbiter on localhost:27019 (with journal = false).

MongoDB **version** is 2.4.3 and pymongo==2.5.2 running on linux Ubuntu 11.10

We configured the cluster with :

```
cfg = {                                                                                
 _id : 'my-data-cluster',
 members : [
   { _id : 0, host : '127.0.0.1:27017' },
   { _id : 1, host : '127.0.0.1:27018' },
   { _id : 2, host : '127.0.0.1:27019', arbiterOnly: true}
 ]
};
rs.initiate(cfg);
```

And use the python call :

```
MongoReplicaSetClient(hosts_or_uri=hosts, replicaSet='my-data-cluster')
```

Fine, then the unit tests are green, the acceptance tests are green. But every morning (unit tests are launched around midnight) all the mongo tests are broken with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    commons/test/test_user_dao.py line 12 in setUp
      self.user_dao = UserDao(self.connection.get(UNIT_TEST))
    commons/src/user_dao.py line 9 in __init__
      self.__create_indexes()
    commons/src/user_dao.py line 14 in __create_indexes
      self.collection.ensure_index('login', pymongo.ASCENDING, unique=True, background=True)
    DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py line 916 in ensure_index
      return self.create_index(key_or_list, cache_for, **kwargs)
    DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py line 823 in create_index
      **self._get_wc_override())
    DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py line 357 in insert
      continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
    lib/src/mongo_connection.py line 19 in wrapper
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    lib/src/mongo_connection.py line 82 in _send_message
      return super(ReconnectingMongoReplicaSetClient, self)._send_message(msg, with_last_error, _connection_to_use)
    DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py line 1360 in _send_message
      rv = self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
    DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py line 1271 in __check_response_to_last_error
      raise OperationFailure(error["err"], error["code"])
   OperationFailure: local.oplog.rs missing. did you drop it? if so restart server
```

I checked the server logs and the only suspect line I see looks like :

```
09:13:53.788 [rsBackgroundSync] replSet db exception in producer: 1000 replSet source for syncing doesn't seem to be await capable -- is it an older version of mongodb?
```

When I restart the three Mongo instances, the tests are back to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we found that we were cleaning mongo databases every night with :

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.forEach( function (d) {
  if (d.name != "admin" && d.name != "config")
     db.getSiblingDB(d.name).dropDatabase();
})
```

But we were dropping db.local which is not a good idea : it holds replicaset config !